# File order error when the files in different operator system

Tags: python, linux, macos, file, csv

#### OS X system

For example, a catalog contain 1000 files in the format of `.csv`. The files are in the order of time-series. And it shows like this:

```
so2-2014-01-02_0000.csv
so2-2014-01-02_0100.csv
so2-2014-01-02_0200.csv
so2-2014-01-02_0300.csv
so2-2014-01-02_0400.csv
.........
```

They are houly data during the first month of 2014.

In my own computer(OSX system), using **Python** code like this:

```
os.chdir("/target_path/")
files = os.listdir('.')
for file in files:
    filename,extname = os.path.splitext(file)
    if extname == '.csv':
        f = pd.read_csv(file)
```

I can read the file by its time order.

```
$>files.head(3)
$>['so2_2014-01-02-00.csv',
   'so2_2014-01-02-01.csv',
   'so2_2014-01-02-02.csv',
   'so2_2014-01-02-03.csv',
   'so2_2014-01-02-04.csv']
```

#### Linux system

By Using `SCP -r`, I move all these file into the Linux cluster for data analysis with more efficiency. With same subroutine in **Python**, the files order **was in chaos**.

```
os.chdir("./target_path/")
files = os.listdir(".)
files[:5]
> ['so2_2014-01-29-19.csv',
 'so2_2014-01-23-21.csv',
 'so2_2014-01-28-02.csv',
 'so2_2014-01-10-14.csv',
 'so2_2014-01-26-00.csv']
```

Comment: do you just want to sort them? like using `files.sort()` then go through the files?

Comment: they are different because all the functions on the `os` module is dependant on the operating system, it seems mac lists files in alphabetical order while linux does not (it probably gives you in order of occurrence on the hard drive)

Comment: from the python manual, os.listdir will return in arbitrary order.

Comment: Files inside a file system folder do _not_ have a particular order! There is absolutely nothing that suggests so. If that happens to be the case in your first example, then that is fine (and interesting), but you certainly can not blindly rely on that! You have to order them to a specific scheme if you need an ordered list.

Comment: @arkascha, I believe the macs store meta data including filenames in alphabetical order in the hidden [.DS_Store](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.DS_Store) for quick retrieval.

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen Why should that be more "quick"? It certainly requires an additional index to be maintained, so definitely should slow things down! And what exactly does "alphabetical order" actually mean? That completely depends on character encoding and collation, obviously. And for most application one wants another order, typically time based. So "blindly" relying that some given order in a list will most likely be the one you were looking for is simply naive...

Comment: Thanks for yours reply.

Comment: @Han Zhengzu, the order is arbitrary,  on linux I believe it is based on the fileindex, `ls -U` outputs *entries in directory order* which should match what you see with os.listdir. Also sorting is based on locale so just sorting is not going to work the same on every system.

Comment: I test `files.sort()` in Linux system multi-times. And the files were always in alphabetical order after sorting.